# Setting pixel values in Nvidia NPP ImageCPU objects?

Tags: c++, image-processing, cuda, nvidia

In the [Nvidia Performance Primitives (NPP)](http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda/nvidia-performance-primitives) image processing examples in the [CUDA SDK distribution](http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-40), images are typically stored on the CPU as `ImageCPU` objects, and images are stored on the GPU as `ImageNPP` objects.

[boxFilterNPP.cpp](http://mlso.hao.ucar.edu/hao/acos/sw/cuda-sdk/CUDALibraries/src/boxFilterNPP/boxFilterNPP.cpp) is an example from the CUDA SDK that uses these `ImageCPU` and `ImageNPP` objects.

When using a filter (convolution) function like `nppiFilter`, it makes sense to define a filter as an `ImageCPU` object. However, I see no clear way setting the values of an `ImageCPU` object.

```
npp::ImageCPU_32f_C1 hostKernel(3,3); //allocate space for 3x3 convolution kernel 

//want to set hostKernel to [-1 0 1; -1 0 1; -1 0 1]

hostKernel[0][0] = -1;   //this doesn't compile
hostKernel(0,0) = -1;    //this doesn't compile
hostKernel.at(0,0) = -1; //this doesn't compile
```

**How can I manually put values into an `ImageCPU` object?**

Notes:

- I didn't actually use `nppiFilter` in the code snippet; I'm just mentioning `nppiFilter` as a motivating example for writing values into an `ImageCPU` object.
- The [boxFilterNPP.cpp](http://mlso.hao.ucar.edu/hao/acos/sw/cuda-sdk/CUDALibraries/src/boxFilterNPP/boxFilterNPP.cpp) example doesn't involve writing directly to an `ImageCPU` object, because `nppiFilterBox` is a special case of `nppiFilter` that uses a built-in gaussian smoothing filter (probably something like [1 1 1; 1 1 1; 1 1 1]).

Comment: it seems like you could use nppiSet   It expects a pixel value and a ROI, but I think you could define an ROI as a single pixel and thereby set the value of a single pixel, if that is what you had in mind.  for an example example refer to section 7.6.2.154 [here](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/CUDALibraries/doc/NPP_Library.pdf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1-channel (e.g. `32f_C1`), this approach works:

```
hostKernel.pixels(0,0) = -1;
```

Answer (score 1):

To assign values to the pixel/matrix:

```
hostKernel.pixels(0,0)[0].x = -1;
```

Comment: When using type `32f_C1`, what does the extra `[0]` index do? In other words, what's the difference between `hostKernel.pixels(0,0)[0]` and `hostKernel.pixels(0,0)`? Also, what is the `x`?

Comment: don't know about the x, meaby it is the value. But the [0] indicates what channel of the image you are trying to change.

A gray scale image have 1 channel, a RGB have 3.

Comment: It turns out that `hostKernel.pixels(0,0)[0].x = -1;` doesn't compile. What does seem to compile and work properly is this: `hostKernel.pixels(0,0) = -1;`  Presumably, if I use a multi-channel image (e.g. `32f_C3`), we would have an extra index to specify the channel like this: `hostKernel.pixels(0,0)][channelIdx] = -1;`

Answer (score 1):

You're saying: "When using a filter (convolution) function like nppiFilter, it makes sense to define a filter as an ImageCPU object."

This is false and a bad idea. Image data is usually stored in "line-padded" format and the image classes shipped with the CUDA SDK samples for NPP do use specialized 2D memory allocators that add padding bytes to the end of each line. That way the first pixel each line lands on a 64-byte aligned address. This is done for performance reasons (on CPUs and GPUs alike).

The kernel arrays used for primitives like nppiFilter on the other hand need to be tightly packed. Which is why the code shown will not work.

Comment: Good point. I also tried defining the filter as an `Npp32s` array. The array is 1D on the host (`NppiSize kernelSize = {3, 3};
Npp32s hostKernel[9] = {-1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 1};`). I used `cudaMallocPitch` to allocate space on the device, and I used `cudaMemcpy2d` to copy `hostKernel` to the device. When I pass my `deviceKernel` into `nppiFilter`, I get error `-3`, which corresponds to `NPP_CUDA_KERNEL_EXECUTION_ERROR`.

Note that calling `nppiFilterBox_8u_1R` works properly with no errors and outputs a visually correct image. (the `Box` version has a pre-defined filter of all ones.)